# How to render Fullcalendar's moreLink based on events

Tags: reactjs, events, fullcalendar, render

Is there a way to access the events of the day when the "+2 more" link shows up?

What I'd like to do is to be able to render it differently based on some properties for that day's events, like so
[image]

I'm using ReactJS, so far using the moreLinkContent property with a function only gives info about the moreLink itself.

[image: FullCalendar being used on ReactJS]

[image: MoreLinkContentArg]

something along the lines of (simplified):

```
moreLinkContent={(moreLinkContentArg) => {
  if (getEventTypeForFirstEventOfDay(moreLinkContentArg) === someType) {
  // render green '2 more +'
  }
  // etc
}}
```

(By events of the day meaning the day the moreLink is being rendered on, not necessarily today.)

Comment: I think you'd probably have to call [getEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents) and have a look through the event list yourself. As you say , the moreLinkContent hooks don't expose that information.

Comment: Is there a way to get the day the moreLink was invoked from? Otherwise I won't be able to filter the events to that day

Comment: That's a good point. According to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/more-link-render-hooks , no there isn't. So I think unfortunately you probably have to abandon this idea. I guess for future you could make a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) to ask fullCalendar to provide more info to the callback.

Answer (score 1):

If you or anyone is looking for a solution, I found one ! (albeit a bit sketchy)

Instead of using the `moreLinkContent` hook, I use the `moreLinkDidMount` hook.
The arguments passed to this hook are similar to the other except you now have access to the DOM element associated.

[Screenshot of moreLinkDidMount hook argument detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13wAK.png)

From there you can navigate up the DOM tree to find a `<td>` parent containing the date in the `data-date` attribute.

[Screenshot of DOM tree and path to find the date data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEL7U.png)

Once you have the date you can fetch your calendar's events and filter them based on this date.
Now you have access to all your usual event's data and can do whatever you want with them. In my case I wanted to display dots with the color of my events.

So far so good, but now if you want to render a custom element, you will need to manually create the DOM elements and inject them.

This is what my code looks like:

```
moreLinkDidMount: (o)=>{

    // Get the date from a parent
    const date = new Date(o.el.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('data-date'));
    
    //Get all the events from the calendar
    const calendarEvents = this.calendarRef.current.calendar.getEvents()

    // Filter the events to get only the events of this day
    const eventsThatDay = calendarEvents.filter((ev)=>{
        return ev._instance.range.start.getFullYear() === date.getFullYear() &&
        ev._instance.range.start.getMonth() === date.getMonth() &&
        ev._instance.range.start.getDate() === date.getDate();
    })

    // If there are events
    if(eventsThatDay.length > 0){

        // Create a new DOM element that will be used as a container for our custom "moreLink" element
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('class', classes.row);

        
        eventsThatDay.forEach((ev)=>{
            const dot = document.createElement('div');
            dot.setAttribute('class', classes.dot);
            dot.setAttribute('style', `background-color: ${ev._def.extendedProps.eventType.color}`)
            div.appendChild(dot);
        })

        //Add the custom element to the DOM
        o.el.append(div);
    }
},
```

And this is what the result looks like:
[Screenshot of calendar with custom event based 'moreLink' element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4vPm.png)

I hope this helps !